# How to get column name based on value

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

```
        A         B         C         D
a  -0.023688  2.410179  1.450520  0.206053
b  -0.251905 -2.213588  1.063327  1.266143
c   0.299368 -0.863838  0.408204 -1.048089
d  -0.025747 -0.988387  0.094055  1.262731
e   1.289997  0.082423 -0.055758  0.536580
f  -0.489682  0.369374 -0.034571 -2.484478
```

In above dataframe based on value such as `1.450520`, get the column name `== C` as output

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any built-in function for doing that, but at least you can do it:

```
for column in df.columns:
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
       if row[column] ==1.450520:
           print(f"value search located: on index: {index} in column {column}")
```